# Java jtable program

Tags: jtable

I am  trying to filter a table which as records the table is create from a Gui and coded. I have a problem where to declare the following expressions in my source code.

```
private MyTableModel tableModel;
private javax.swing.JTable jtblSampleTable;
private TableRowSorter sorter ;
```

And where to initialize it.

Comment: Sorry mate but I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know where do I declare this values. Before the main class inside the main class or inside a class .

Comment: See [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jtable/info) in the [tag:jtable] tag.

Comment: I need a model in order to make filtering , but I do not know
how to setup my Jtable with a model, that uses resultset for
data , instead of objects. My table's code is generated from GUI I didn't code the table. So I am stuck and I don't know how to filter the table

Answer (score 1):

Where you declare an `object`, it completely depends upon your intended use for it.

In this case, you are declaring `private` objects that can only be accessed inside a single `class` or `method`

If you only require the use of one of those objects inside a single `method` and not the entire `class`, then declare the `private` object inside the `method` that it is needed. However, this will mean that this object will not be accessible outside of the method. If you require the use of this object throughout your `class`, then declare it inside your `class` and not inside a `method`. This will allow all of the `methods` inside your `class` to access the `object`.

If the `object` needs to be accessed by other classes, then it must be declared as `public`.

Cheers.